# Different result depending on isolate order of variables Lorentz transformations deduction

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

I was searching for deductions of the Lorentz transformations and found one (in wikipedia) that caught my attention due to its simplicity, but when i'm trying to reproduce it changing the order of isolate variables i can't get the same result. So, i'll write the steps of the wikipedia deduction (all with "a") and, together with them, my own steps(all with "b") for a direct comparison.

Since space is assumed to be homogeneous, the transformation must be linear. The most general linear relationship is obtained with four constant coefficients, A, B, γ, and b:

$$x'=\gamma x + b t \tag{1}$$
$$t'= Ax+Bt \tag{2}$$

An object at rest in the R' frame at position $x'=0$ moves with constant velocity $v$ in the R frame. Hence the transformation must yield $x'=0$ if $x=vt$. Therefore $b=-\gamma v$, **but this implies that $\gamma = \frac{-b}{v}$ when $v\neq 0$**

So we can write (1) as

$$x'=\gamma x -(\gamma v) t =\gamma (x-vt)\tag{3a} $$

**or**

$$x'=(\frac{-b}{v}) x + b t = b(\frac{-x}{v}+t)\tag{3b}$$

Now, for principle of relativity this equations leads us to

$$x=\gamma (x'+vt') \tag{4a}$$
$$x=b(\frac{x'}{v}+t')\tag{4b}$$

Since the speed of light is the same in all frames of reference, for the case of a light signal, the transformation must guarantee that $t=\frac{x}{c}$ when $t'=\frac{x'}{c}$

if we replace in (3a) and (4a) **and in (3b) and (4b)**:

$$x'=\gamma x(1-\frac{v}{c})\tag{5a} $$
$$x'= bx(\frac{-1}{v}+\frac{1}{c})\tag{5b}$$

$$x=\gamma x'(1+\frac{v}{c}) \tag{6a}$$
$$x=bx'(\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{c})\tag{6b}$$

Then, multiplying (5a) with (6a) **or (5b) with (6b)** we obtain, respectively
$$xx' = \gamma^2 xx' (1-\frac{v}{c})(1+\frac{v}{c}) \Longrightarrow \gamma^2 =\frac{1}{1-(\frac{v}{c})^2} \tag{7a}$$

$$x'x=bx'x(\frac{-1}{v}+\frac{1}{c})(\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{c})\Longrightarrow b^2 = \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{c})^2-(\frac{1}{v})^2}\tag{7b}$$

And now comes my problem: between eq (2) and (3a) we state that $\gamma = \frac{-b}{v}$ but, for (7b)

$$\frac{-b}{v}=\frac{-\sqrt{\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{c})^2-(\frac{1}{v})^2}}}{v}=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{(\frac{v}{c})^2-1}}\neq{\gamma} \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$$

Maybe is such a simple thing but I really can't figure out where is my mistake. Help me plz :C

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the mistake lies in (4b). You have assumed that $b$ does not change, going from $v$ to $-v$. But in that case, $x=0$ must correspond to $x' = - v t$, implying $b =+ v \gamma$.

Therefore, the two $b$s in (5b) and (6b) are not the same but differ by a sign.